# Where are the densest locations for collecting coins?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I'm saving up for a 9999 coin item in the shop (post-game content) so I need a lot of coins. Outside of the few vault chambers associated with a few power moons, are there any dense locations for farming coins?

Comment: The Festival in the Metro Kingdom is a fairly popular place to farm coins. It can give roughly 300 coins per 3-4 minutes, and is fast and simple to repeat, but I'm not sure how it compares with other spots enough to make an answer out of this.

Comment: I've also seen a video on a location in Bowser's Kingdom that looks pretty good as well

Comment: I'm not sure how it stacks up to other locations; but anywhere there's a Tostarena slot machine thing you can get a net of 30 coins per win; and everything is on a fairly low frequency timer, so it's pretty easy to get coins every time.  There may be quicker locations to just keep traveling to though.

Comment: I was doing the last, last world and by the time I completed it I had gained 2~3k coins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With the release of v1.2.0, [Luigi’s Balloon World](http://mario.wikia.com/wiki/Balloon_World) is now the best way to collect coins.**

Luigi’s Balloon World is a minigame added in an update on February 21, 2018 and is unlocked after defeating Bowser.

Talk to Luigi on any stage to view a list of balloons hidden by other players. You can earn money multiple ways:

- Finding balloons hidden by other players.
- Having other players fail to find a balloon you hid
- Getting a streak by finding multiple balloons without failing
- Ranking up by completing challenges

I can’t say for sure whether this method is faster than the bonus area in Bowser’s Castle, but it is certainly a more fun and less repetitive way to earn money,

[image: Earning 1000 coins from rank up]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the growing consensus is that the **bonus (beanstalk) areas are the densest**.

Arekkz recommends the bonus area in Bowser's Kingdom. Turn around from the "Beneath the Keep" checkpoint, follow the roof on your right towards the column of gold rings, and the seed/planter is on that side of the lower level. Estimated 150–175 coins, and you'll spawn so you can easily run it again.

As an alternative, IGN and AbdullahSmash recommend a loop through the Wooded Kingdom's Observatory Deck bonus area. Starting from that checkpoint, grabbing the purple coins, heading towards the seed dispenser, coin purse in the flowers below, and returning it to the Observation Deck, IGN estimates you can make 1000 coins in eight minutes.

In any event, the bonus levels are definitely faster than pulling coins in the slot machine or other schemes that involve getting 30 coins and repeatedly respawning. But here's hoping that there's an [automated, infinite coin location](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elmiCyTsYUw) hidden somewhere.

Comment: The bonus area in Bowser's Kingdom is definitely the fastest.  You can max out at 185 coins per run, but that takes longer than 180 coins and I don't recommend it.  You don't even have to move- once you get to the platform, throw Cappie with Y to collect the rocket flowers, then all you need to do is jump (and also collect one more rocket flower along the way). If you never move the camera or walk stick, Mario will continue straight to the goal.